# Does $f$ have a local maximum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$, $f\in{C^{2}}$, can I claim, that if $f$ have a critical point $\widehat{x_{0}}$ and is such that every eigenvalue of $D(\nabla(f))$ is positive then $f$ have a local maximum???

Any idea about if this is true because I´m not completely sure, but I have not founded a counterexample, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix (evaluated at $x_0$) are strictly positive? If so, then the Hessian is positive definite, and $x_0$ must be a (local) minimum of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that ${\bf p}$ is a critical point of $f$ and that all eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix
$$H:=\left[{\partial^2 f\over\partial x_i\partial x_k}\right]_{\bf p}$$
are positive. This implies that the quadratic form
$$q({\bf X}):={\bf X}' H{\bf X}$$
is positive definite.

*Proof.* In suitable orthonormal coordinates $(\bar x_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ one has
$$q({\bf X})={\bf X}' H{\bf X}=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda _k \bar X_k^2\geq\lambda_m|{\bf X}|^2\ ,$$
where $\lambda_m>0$ denotes the smallest eigenvalue of $H$.$\qquad\square$

We now invoke Taylor's theorem:
$$f({\bf p}+{\bf X})=f({\bf p})+{1\over2}{\bf X}' H{\bf X}+o\bigl(|{\bf X}|^2\bigr)\qquad({\bf X}\to{\bf 0})\ .$$
This implies
$$f({\bf p}+{\bf X})-f({\bf p})\geq\left({\lambda_m\over2}+o(1)\right)\>|{\bf X}|^2\qquad ({\bf X}\to{\bf 0})$$
and shows that $f$ has a "strict" *local minimum* at ${\bf p}$.